# React-Native-Ble-Plx [BleError: Cannot start scanning operation]

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing the react-native-cli project on the Android platform.A navigation project that provides guidance inside the building with iBeacons. You choose the place you want to go and then it guides you.I'm using the react-native-blue-plex library. I did the development on a device with android 5.0 (I know it's very old, but I didn't have any other devices). The application works smoothly on my device. Android 5.0 also does not require any permissions. I started working with devices above Android 5.0, for example, android 11.0 and above. He wants permission for these devices. i feel like I've solved the permission problem. Requests location permission for Bluetooth. It also asks for browsing and connection permission. I'm successfully getting the Location Permission, but I'm getting stuck with a problem with the browsing and connection permissions and I'm getting the error I wrote in the header.
My error is =  LOG  [BleError: Cannot start scanning operation] how can i fix this error.

```
My androidManifest.xml file :
<!-- Start bluetooth permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
  <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />

  <!-- End bluetooth permissions -->
```

My ContextApi State file:

```
    const requestPermissions = async () => {
  const requestFineLocationPermission = () => {
    return PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Location Permission',
        message:
          'This application needs Location permission in order to work correctly.',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
  };

  const requestBluetoothScanPermission = () => {
    return PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
      {
        title: 'Bluetooth Scan Permission',
        message:
          'This application needs Bluetooth Scan permission in order to work correctly.',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
  };

  const requestBluetoothConnectPermission = () => {
    return PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
      {
        title: 'Bluetooth Connect Permission',
        message:
          'This application needs Bluetooth Connect permission in order to work correctly.',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
  };

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return requestBluetoothConnectPermission()
      .then(result => {
        if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          return requestBluetoothScanPermission();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          return requestFineLocationPermission();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Bluetooth scan permission not granted');
        }
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('All permissions granted');
          return true;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Bluetooth connect permission not granted');
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn(err);
        return false;
      });
  } else {
    // iOS üzerinde herhangi bir izin istememize gerek yok
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
};
```

Scanning Function :

```
// Scanning Operations
  const scanForDevices = useCallback(() => {
    const debouncedScan = debounce(() => {
      let deviceFound = false;
  
      manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          Alert.alert(
            'Error',
            'Lütfen bluetoothunuzu açıp kapatınız ve uygulamayı yeniden başlatınız',
            [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')}],
            {cancelable: false},
          );
          return;
        }
        if (device.localName === defaultDeviceName) {
          deviceFound = true;
  
          const base64 = RNFetchBlob.base64;
          const advertisingData = stringToBytes(
            base64.decode(device.manufacturerData),
          );
          const rssi = device.rssi;
          const major = advertisingData[21];
          const minor = advertisingData[23];
  
          setBleData(rssi, major, minor);
  
          console.log(matchedDataRef.current);
        }
      });
  
      console.log('scanForDevices is finished');
    }, 1500);
  
    debouncedScan();
  }, [setBleData]);
```

Comment: Did u find any solution? I'm facing the same issue. I already granted bluetooth and location permissions and stil getting [BleError: Cannot start scanning operation]

Comment: @4aLifeTime unfortunaltely not yet it execute with 10 11 13 but dont execute in android 12.